# Error while running through command line in springs

Tags: spring, command-line, junit

I have a test class that uses @Autowired annotation and @ContextConfiguration and @Category annotations.

The test tuns fine when its run through eclipse.
But when i try running it through Command line, it is throwing the following error.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 25.690s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jun 12 09:56:48 GMT+05:30 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 31M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:2.14.1:integration-test (default) on project OmnitureSeleniumTests: Execution default of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:2.14.1:integration-test failed: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.runner.Request.classes(Lorg/junit/runner/Computer;[Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/junit/runner/Request;
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreWrapper.createReqestAndRun(JUnitCoreWrapper.java:128)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreWrapper.executeEager(JUnitCoreWrapper.java:111)
 [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreWrapper.execute(JUnitCoreWrapper.java:84)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreProvider.invoke(JUnitCoreProvider.java:138)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
[ERROR] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray2(ReflectionUtils.java:208)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:159)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:87)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:95)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

I am using junit 4.8.2 and 
maven-failsafe-plugin:2.14.1

Answer (score 0):

There could be many configuration / environmental differences when running maven from Eclipse vs command line:

1. The maven version / path. In Eclipse the actual maven binary can be default / explicitly set via preferences, whereas in command line your OS will pick the first one available on your PATH env var. Check maven version using `mvn -version`
2. Maven user / global settings.xml. When running through command line typically ~/.m2/settings.xml is used but this can be explicitly overridden on Eclipse preferences
3. Maven local repository cache. If you have discrepancy on 1 and/or 2, you could end up with different local repository cache. Incorrect artifact distribution could cause build to fail if performed against different local repository cache.
4. Eclipse maven could use different version of JVM than your command line.

Answer (score 0):

i have changed the version of maven-failsafe-plugin to 2.6 and it is running fine thru command line now :)